# Time-consuming substitution in sympy

Tags: python, matlab, replace, sympy, substitution

[image: 1]

I have a very long polynomial in **Sympy** that I want to substitute with numbers. But this substitution will take a lot of time, while the same polynomial in MATLAB software will be output in less than one second.
How can I solve this problem in **Python**?

I just tried for exapmle: polynomial.subs([(k11,9600000000.00000), (k12,3066000000.0000),...])

Comment: MATLAB is very often much faster than python, otherwise they would not be able to charge large amounts of money for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a numerical result, you probably want to look at lambdify, which converts the symbolic polynomial to a numerical function for faster evaluation...

```
f = lambdify(coefficient_list, polynomial)
result = f(*coefficient_values)
```

Comment: In addition, if there are patterns that are oft repeated in the polynomial, I think your lambdified code will benefit by adding `, cse=True` before the closing parenthesis in your lambdify call. This is an option that will create a sequence of intermediate values that will only have to be pre-computed once instead of every time that they are encountered in the expression. It would be interesting to know the results of the time improvement.

Comment: How can I give lambdify a list of coefficient_values for input?

Comment: There are two steps: 1. You convert the symbolic expression to a numerical function with `lambdify`. Here, you would have to construct a list with your symbolic coefficients, for example `coefficient_list=[k1, k2, k3, ...]`. 2. Then, you evaluate the numerical function giving in the coefficient values, for example: `coefficient_values=[0.5, 1, 1.5, ....]`. Note that the order of those numbers must respect the order of the symbols into `coefficient_list`.

Comment: The problem is that it does not accept [0.5,1,1.5,...] as input

Comment: Obviusly you have to insert your values. Moreover, with the very little details you provided in your question, I'm afraid I can't help you any longer ....

Comment: I had not noticed the star before coefficient_values
thank you